# How can I tell an array of lines objects is approximately making closed region?

Tags: java, android, math, computer-science, computational-geometry

I am making a drawing app where the user can erase what they have drawn.

One of the neat ways I am trying to figure out how they can can erase aside from backtracking where they've touched is to erase an enclosed area they have designated.

The User Story would be the :

> ```
>  - user would draw something that resembles an enclosed area
>  - If it is an enclosed area, mark the area as ready to delete
>  - User clicks on delete
>  - the pixels inside the region are written with the delete color
> ```

I've seen this done in other drawing apps. Math is not my area of expertise. I'm not even sure where to look for this answer.

The app already has the ability to drawLine()'s on a bitmap

Comment: Do you want a closed circle, or does any closed polygon work?

Comment: i guess any closed polygon. I have an array of line objects collected from the user where the tail of one line is the head of another

Comment: Can the lines cross over one another?  Or do they have to only intersect at the endpoints?

Comment: So you are interested in the following: given a sequence of line segments where each segment starts where the previous ends, do the lines form (roughly) a closed polygon?

Comment: yes! That's what I am trying to get at ... but don't where to start after the sequence of line segments have been collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So judging from the revised question in the comments: "given a sequence of line segments where each segment starts where the previous ends, do the lines form (roughly) a closed polygon?" this should not be too difficult.

Simply take the head of the first segment and compare it to the tail of the last segment. If they are sufficiently close together, then the segments roughly form a closed (possibly self-intersecting) polygon.

So if you have `n` segments formed by the sequence of points `p_0,...,p_n`, you can consider the Euclidean distance between `p_0` and `p_n`. The idea is as follows:

```
if dist(p_0,p_n) < THRESHOLD
    create a new segment [p_n,p_0] closing off the polygon
    delete pixels in the enclosed region
```

`dist(p_0,p_n)` can be implemented as `sqrt((p_0x - p_nx)^2 + (p_0y - p_ny)^2)`. The variable `THRESHOLD` will be some constant determining how much error you want to tolerate between the first point and the last point.

Comment: OMG tskuzzy! I can totally do this. Thanks to both you and templatetypedef!

Comment: Got a little too excited =( What's not clear is what happens after creating [p_n,p_0]. I guess I need an array of pixels that equals the polygon so that I can iterate throught it and delete it. How do I go from closed graph of segments and store it as an area? Does that make sense what I am saying?

Comment: Technically the answer you supplied is the answer to my posted question. However, it begs another as I mentioned above.

Comment: Good question. I would use a flood-fill algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill . If you need help with the implementation of this, feel free to ask it as another question.

Comment: Wow this is so awesome, I will definitely study this. You've been really helpful.